# How do I include a custom module translation?

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I have a Drupal 8 custom module (custom_module) and a custom_module-8.x-1.0.da.po file I added to sites/default/files/translations, but my translations are not getting Imported during the module installation, even though translations are available for import in admin/reports/translations. Am I missing any step?

I don't want to put my custom_module-8.x-1.0.da.po file in sites/default/files/translations; I prefer it to be inside the module directory, if possible.

Comment: Have you added `interface translation project` and `interface translation server pattern` definitions to custom_module.info.yml? You might find useful info [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/162439/providing-translations-for-custom-modules)

Comment: You can use a custom path for your translation file by setting the `interface translation server pattern` to whatever you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `interface translation project` and `interface translation server pattern definitions` to custom_module.info.yml.
You can use a custom path for your translation po file by setting the `interface translation server pattern` to whatever you want.